# Private networks with SCVMM 2012 SP1 and Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines, scvmm, system-center

In my lab I have two hyper-v host running Windows 2012 server. For lab and test purposes I want to have private networks that are available on both hosts, and where the VMs on those networks are able to communicate with each other on both hosts. From what I understand, this is possible with NVGRE, and it's easiest to manage using SCVMM 2012 SP1.

So I have set up SCVMM, and for the last couple of weeks I've been trying to set up private networks on the hosts, but can't seem to figure it out no mather how much I try. I tried creating a logical network I called LabNet, and several isolated VM Networks, then associate the logical network to a NIC on the host. When I try to connect the VM to the VM Network, I usually get an error. There are a lot of different errors, like the virtual NIC not having a CA address from the VM-pool, and when I create a VM-pool (which I thought was optional), I get errors on the Logical Switch.

I haven't had much luck finding resources and examples where people have isolated "private" networks running with SCVMM 2012 SP1 and Hyper-V 2012. So how would I go about creating one correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it.

From within SCVMM, go to Fabric and create a new logical network.

On the name tab to select the check box: 'Allow new VM networks created on this logical network to use network virtualization.'

On the Network Site Tab be sure 'all hosts' is selected and add a VLAN and IP subnet. If you don't use VLAN's you can set it to 0.

On one of your cluster nodes, go to properties and create a virtual switch and set it to 'Internal'.

on your VM, go to properties -> Hardware Configuration -> Network Adapters Connect it to the VM network you set to internal.

All VM's that you connect to this Virtual Network will see each other and nothing else unless you have a second NIC on those VM's connecting to a virtual switch associated with a physical NIC on the node.

Answer (score 0):

On pools specifically:

When allocating an address from a pool, you need to create a new machine. The only way to get an address in a pool into an existing machine is to set it in the VM. The next time VMM reads the VM settings, it will see the address and allocate it from the pool.